# I'm curious about the JavaScript combination

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, ecmascript-6, combinations

I have an array of items.

```
// groupA,groupB,groupC,groupD length 4 = I want to be 4 column
const arr = [
  { seq: 253, type: "a", group:'A' },
  { seq: 258, type: "a", group:'B' },
  { seq: 259, type: "a", group:'C' },
  { seq: 260, type: "a", group:'C' },
  { seq: 295, type: "a", group:'D' },
  { seq: 295, type: "b", group:'D' },
  { seq: 295, type: "c", group:'D' },
  { seq: 296, type: "a", group:'D' },
  { seq: 296, type: "b", group:'D' },
  { seq: 297, type: "c", group:'D' },
]
```

I want to combine these arrays to create a table like the one below.

```
[
  [{seq:253, type:'a', group:'A'}, {seq:258, type:'a', group:'B'}, {seq:259, type:'a', group:'C'}, {seq: 295, type:'a', group:'D'}],
  [{seq:253, type:'a', group:'A'}, {seq:258, type:'a', group:'B'}, {seq:259, type:'a', group:'C'}, {seq: 295, type:'b', group:'D'}],
  [{seq:253, type:'a', group:'A'}, {seq:258, type:'a', group:'B'}, {seq:259, type:'a', group:'C'}, {seq: 295, type:'c', group:'D'}],
  [{seq:253, type:'a', group:'A'}, {seq:258, type:'a', group:'B'}, {seq:259, type:'a', group:'C'}, {seq: 296, type:'a', group:'D'}],
  [{seq:253, type:'a', group:'A'}, {seq:258, type:'a', group:'B'}, {seq:259, type:'a', group:'C'}, {seq: 296, type:'b', group:'D'}],
  [{seq:253, type:'a', group:'A'}, {seq:258, type:'a', group:'B'}, {seq:259, type:'a', group:'C'}, {seq: 297, type:'c', group:'D'}],
  [{seq:253, type:'a', group:'A'}, {seq:258, type:'a', group:'B'}, {seq:260, type:'a', group:'C'}, {seq: 295, type:'a', group:'D'}],
  [{seq:253, type:'a', group:'A'}, {seq:258, type:'a', group:'B'}, {seq:260, type:'a', group:'C'}, {seq: 295, type:'b', group:'D'}],
  [{seq:253, type:'a', group:'A'}, {seq:258, type:'a', group:'B'}, {seq:260, type:'a', group:'C'}, {seq: 295, type:'c', group:'D'}],
  [{seq:253, type:'a', group:'A'}, {seq:258, type:'a', group:'B'}, {seq:260, type:'a', group:'C'}, {seq: 296, type:'a', group:'D'}],
  [{seq:253, type:'a', group:'A'}, {seq:258, type:'a', group:'B'}, {seq:260, type:'a', group:'C'}, {seq: 296, type:'b', group:'D'}],
  [{seq:253, type:'a', group:'A'}, {seq:258, type:'a', group:'B'}, {seq:260, type:'a', group:'C'}, {seq: 297, type:'c', group:'D'}],
]
```

However, I tried with the recursive algorithm below, but it produces more than a hundred items.

```
const getCombinations = (arr, 4) => { // group length 4
    const results = [];
    if (selectNumber === 1) return arr.map((el) => [el]);

    arr.forEach((fixed, index, origin) => {
      console.log("fixed", fixed);
      const rest = origin.slice(index + 1);
      const combinations = getCombinations(rest, selectNumber - 1);
      const attached = combinations.map((el) => [fixed, ...el]);
      results.push(...attached);
    });

    state.combinationList = results;
    return results;
  };
```

```
[
[{seq: 253, type: "a", group:'A'},{seq: 258, type: "a" group:'B'},{seq: 259, type: "a", group:"C"},{seq: 260, type: "a", group:"C"}],
[{seq: 253, type: "a", group:'A'},{seq: 258, type: "a" group:'B'},{seq: 259, type: "a", group:"C"},{seq: 295, type: "a", group:"D"}],
[{seq: 253, type: "a", group:'A'},{seq: 258, type: "a" group:'B'},{seq: 259, type: "a", group:"C"},{seq: 295, type: "b", group:"D"}],
[{seq: 253, type: "a", group:'A'},{seq: 258, type: "a" group:'B'},{seq: 259, type: "a", group:"C"},{seq: 295, type: "c", group:"D"}],
[{seq: 253, type: "a", group:'A'},{seq: 258, type: "a" group:'B'},{seq: 259, type: "a", group:"C"},{seq: 296, type: "a", group:"D"}],
[{seq: 253, type: "a", group:'A'},{seq: 258, type: "a" group:'B'},{seq: 259, type: "a", group:"C"},{seq: 296, type: "b", group:"D"}],
[{seq: 253, type: "a", group:'A'},{seq: 258, type: "a" group:'B'},{seq: 259, type: "a", group:"C"},{seq: 297, type: "c", group:"D"}],
[{seq: 253, type: "a", group:'A'},{seq: 258, type: "a" group:'B'},{seq: 260, type: "a", group:"C"},{seq: 295, type: "a", group:"D"}],
[{seq: 253, type: "a", group:'A'},{seq: 258, type: "a" group:'B'},{seq: 260, type: "a", group:"C"},{seq: 295, type: "b", group:"D"}],
[{seq: 253, type: "a", group:'A'},{seq: 258, type: "a" group:'B'},{seq: 260, type: "a", group:"C"},{seq: 295, type: "c", group:"D"}],
[{seq: 253, type: "a", group:'A'},{seq: 258, type: "a" group:'B'},{seq: 260, type: "a", group:"C"},{seq: 296, type: "a", group:"D"}],
[{seq: 253, type: "a", group:'A'},{seq: 258, type: "a" group:'B'},{seq: 260, type: "a", group:"C"},{seq: 296, type: "b", group:"D"}],
[{seq: 253, type: "a", group:'A'},{seq: 258, type: "a" group:'B'},{seq: 260, type: "a", group:"C"},{seq: 297, type: "c", group:"D"}],
[{seq: 253, type: "a", group:'A'},{seq: 258, type: "a" group:'B'},{seq: 295, type: "a", group:"D"},{seq: 296, type: "a", group:"D"}],
[{seq: 253, type: "a", group:'A'},{seq: 258, type: "a" group:'B'},{seq: 295, type: "a", group:"D"},{seq: 296, type: "b", group:"D"}],
[{seq: 253, type: "a", group:'A'},{seq: 258, type: "a" group:'B'},{seq: 295, type: "a", group:"D"},{seq: 297, type: "c", group:"D"}],
...more 100 item
]
```

Sadly, I stay awake all night. I would be very grateful if anyone could help.
thank you..

Comment: Not coding related, but sleep is important. The [docs](https://www.webmd.com/sleep-disorders/sleep-requirements) say you should get at least 7 hours of sleep.

Comment: It's not clear to me how the table is formed. For instance, in the first row of the results table, why does `{seq: 295, type:'a'}` appear instead of `{seq: 260, type:'a'}`?

Comment: Logic is completely unclear to me too.

Comment: thank you. I want to forget everything and go to sleep. I'm Korean. I'm sorry I can't speak English well @Michael M.

Comment: @enhzflep Sorry for the misunderstanding.
I want to show rows by group. I edited the post.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen sorry. I am not good at English, so there is a problem with communication

Comment: It looks like you are generating a _cartesian product_.

Comment: @Wyck Thank you to everyone.
Special thanks to Wyck.
It was the answer I was looking for. I didn't know Cartesian calculations. I need to study a bit more. thank you

Answer (score 0):

hope this code help for you

```js
const arr = [
    { seq: 253, type: "a", cate:'groupA' },
    { seq: 258, type: "a", cate:'groupB' },
    { seq: 259, type: "a", cate:'groupC' },
    { seq: 260, type: "a", cate:'groupC' },
    { seq: 295, type: "a", cate:'groupD' },
    { seq: 295, type: "b", cate:'groupD' },
    { seq: 295, type: "c", cate:'groupD' },
    { seq: 296, type: "a", cate:'groupD' },
    { seq: 296, type: "b", cate:'groupD' },
    { seq: 297, type: "c", cate:'groupD' },
]
let result = [];
const groupList = [...new Set(arr.map(item => item.cate))];
const dataByGroup = [];
for (let i = 0; i < groupList.length; i++) {
    const filtered = arr.filter(item => item.cate === groupList[i]);
    dataByGroup.push(filtered);
}
let maxSize = dataByGroup.reduce((pre, cur) => cur.length > pre ? cur.length : pre, 0);
for (let i = 0 ; i < maxSize; i ++) {
    let row = [];
    for (let j = 0 ; j < dataByGroup.length; j++) {
        row.push(dataByGroup[j][i] || dataByGroup[j][i % (dataByGroup[j].length)])
    }
    result.push(row);
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```